# How to read the values inside the json array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json like

```
var obj={
"address":{
       "addlin1":"",
       "addlin2":""
         },
 "name":"sam",
 "score":[{"maths":"ten",
            "science":"two",
             "pass":false
           }]
}
```

Now when Iam trying to modify the json iam try an array variable and passing above json to that like

```
var data=JSON.parse(obj);
var json={}; 
json['name']=data['name'];
json['address']={};
json['address']['addressline1']=data['address']['addlin1'];
json['address']['addressline2']=data['address']['addlin2'];
json['marks']={};
json['maths']=data['score']['maths'];
```

For name and address I was able to form the json as i was expecting.But for marks I was unable.May be in obj json score values are in [ ]

So,when i  console the json it is in this way

```
"name":"sam",
"address":{
   "addresslin1":"",
   "addresslin2":""
     },
  "score":{}
  }
```

So how can I also read the values inside [] array.

Can someone help me
Thanks

Comment: youre nearly there - score is an array according to your first bit of code so access the first object in the score array and then continue as you were `score[0].maths`. You can use dot notation with javascript objects too, if you prefer along the lines of `data.address.addlin1`

Comment: `obj` isn't JSON... that's at least part of your problem.  Just use `obj` directly.

Answer (score 3):

```
json['maths']=data['score'][0]['maths'];
```

if you're not sure that data['score'] has any elements you can check prior to reading maths key:

```
if (data['score'].length) {
    json['maths']=data['score'][0]['maths'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data['score']` is an array, so you can't read it like that

```
json['maths']=data['score']['maths'];
```

you have to read it like that:

```
json['maths'] = data['score'][0].maths;
```

Also, `obj` is not a JSON, but a JavaScript object. You can use it directly.

```
json['maths'] = obj['score'][0].maths;
```

A JSON is a string, like that:

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
var json = "{"address":{"addlin1":"","addlin2":""},"name":"sam","score":[{"maths":"ten","science":"two","pass":false}]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

create another json2 to contain score data then assign to json.

for example :

```
        var json={}; 
        json2 = {}
        json2[0] = 1;
        json2[1] = 2;
        json[0] = json2;
```